# fsolve() gives me two different solutions taking the same equations and initial conditions

Tags: python, fsolve

I am using fsolve(eqs,initial_condition) in python but I defined the function eqs in two different ways, by meaning the same (same equations in both cases). However it gets different outputs and I do not see where the error is. I have attached the code used.

If you rearrange the equations you'll see that they are the same (in the second block x[0] is the x in the first block, x[1] would be y in the first block and x[-1] would be equal to lamda in the first block)

```
#First block
from scipy.optimize import fsolve
import numpy as np

def my_function(z):
    x = z[0]
    y = z[1]
    lamda = z[2]
    F = np.empty(3)
    F[0] = -lamda*x/8 + 2*x -16
    F[1] = -lamda*y/2 + 2*y -12
    F[2] = x**2/16 + y**2/4 -1

    return F

zGuess = np.array([8,6,10]) 
z = fsolve(my_function,zGuess)
print('Valor de x:',z[0])
print('Valor de y:',z[1])
print('Valor de lambda:',z[2])

#Second block
from scipy.optimize import fsolve
import numpy as np

a = np.array([4,2])
centroid = np.array([8,6])


def eqs(x):
 return [x[0]-centroid[0]/(1-x[-1]/a[0]**2),x[1]-centroid[1]/(1- 
x[-1]/a[1]**2),x[0]**2/a[0]**2 + x[1]**2/a[1]**2 -1]

zGuess = np.array([8,6,10])
sol = fsolve(eqs,zGuess)
print('Valor de x:',sol[0])
print('Valor de y:',sol[1])
print('Valor de lambda:',sol[2])
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)